# Newly created files not appearing in Android Studio's "Device File Explorer", how to refresh?

Tags: android, android-studio, caching, adb, refresh

Android Studio's "Device File Explorer" allows the developer to see files stored on the Android devices, for instance in `/data/data/my.app/cache/`.

**Problem**: It works great the first time I open the folder, but then I can't get it to show new files that my app has just created.

A workaround is to restart Android Studio, that makes all new files appear correctly, but it wastes time and is inconvenient when debugging.

The UI does not seem to have a "refresh" button, or I missed it:

[image]

Note: I am not talking about "File Explorer" which shows project resources.

Answer (score 3):

You can synchronize with shortcut key **CTRL+F5**

or by Right clicking on item then synchronize to refresh directory without restarting Android studio.

[image: Refernce screenshot]

Comment: If still you're having issues with synchronize navigate pointer to root folder of your app then synchronize and open the tree you will find updated files.